# Unable to deploy ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core 1) to Azure: not enough space

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I'm trying to deploy the basic vanila Api App from the official tutorial [Create an ASP.NET 5 web app in Visual Studio Code](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-app-using-vscode/) to Azure, but I'm hitting "There is not enough space on the disk" problem. I'm new to Azure and I'm using the trial account.

Is there something that I could do make the deployment lean and not exceed the disk space?

Full error stack:

```
remote: Restore failed
remote: There is not enough space on the disk.
remote:
remote:
remote: Feeds used:
remote:     https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote:
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
```

Comment: what is the size of your app?

Comment: I think you need to create a block storage and assign it to your VM or Application service, it's not included by default as far as I know. Block storage you pay per GB used

Comment: It's a known issue with Git continuous deployment to Free/Shared tiers of App Service not having enough temp storage to restore all the packages required. One workaround is to just publish from Visual Studio... https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anthony Chew says it seems to be a known issue.

My solution was to upgrade my subscription to Basic - still part of the free trial.

Answer (score 2):

## Cross Platform Free/Shared Tier Solution

Even without a free trial, we can publish an ASP.NET Core RC1 application to a Free/Shared Azure Web App. Use `dnu publish` then deploy with FTP. This works cross platform. We do not need Visual Studio, msbuild, Web Deploy, nor a free Azure trial.

Here is an example.

## Example Steps

(1) Use rc1-final with Core CLR. (2) Then scaffold the app with [Yeoman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnet). (3) Next, restore the packages. (4) Finally, publish the application; be sure to include the `active` runtime in the output.

```
C:\> dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final -runtime coreclr                       (1)
C:\> yo aspnet webbasic MyApp                                        (2) 
C:\MyApp> cd MyApp
C:\MyApp> dnu restore                                                (3)
C:\MyApp> dnu publish --configuration release -runtime active        (4)
```

The package is in the `MyApp\bin\output` directory. Use FTP to deploy it to a Free/Shared Azure Web App. The first deployment takes about 15-20 minutes because we're including every package and the runtime.

```
C:\MyApp\bun\output              /site

approot                          approot
log                                   
wwwroot                          wwwroot
```

We need to publish `approot` and `wwwroot` to the `site` directory.

## Example Result

[image: Live Basic Web App on Azure.]